# [Error: Can't use $text with String.]

Tags: mongodb

I want to use `$text` for searching product by title using text searching for mongodb:

Code:

```
var scemmaa = new mongoose.Schema(product);
scemmaa.index({ title: 'text' }); 
Product.find({$text: { $search: query}});
```

but it always log these error :`[Error: Can't use $text with String.]`

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to show what `product` and `query` contain?

Comment: Did you solve the problem?